# How can i call function in code behind in if condition

Tags: c#

I want to call function in code behind in if condition. I have this code in VB.net but I cant convert it to C#. this is VB code:

```
 Dim SessionList As New List(Of Users)
 If SessionList.Where(Function(x) x.Title = My.Computer.Name).Count = 0 Then
            Dim TempUser As Users
            TempUser.Title = My.Computer.Name
            SessionList.Add(TempUser)
            Application("SessionList") = SessionList
        End If
```

my script is:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        window.setInterval("Check_Message()", 3000);
    };

    function Check_Message(){
        var temp=httpGet("Default.aspx?Check=1");
        if (temp.length>0)
        {
            var TempMessage=$("#lblRecived").html();
            $("#lblRecived").html(TempMessage+temp);
        }
    }

    function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
        var xmlHttp = null;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open( "GET", theUrl, false );
        xmlHttp.send( null );
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the C# version:

```
List<Users> SessionList = new List<Users>();
if (SessionList.Where(x => x.Title == System.Environment.MachineName).Count() == 0) {
    Users TempUser = default(Users);
    TempUser.Title = My.Computer.Name;
    SessionList.Add(TempUser);
    Application("SessionList") = SessionList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (SessionList.Where(x => x.Title == My.Computer.Name).Count = 0)        
{        
...       
}
```

See if it helps.